# sort the json based on two fields

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have the json response which I want to sort data based on two fields Geo field need to sort as alphabetical order and salesStage fields in identified,qualified,closed won order

```js
const summary_data = [
{Geo:"US West",SalesStage:"Closed Won",count:2,pipelinevalue:356},
{Geo:"US East",SalesStage:"Closed Won",count:8,pipelinevalue:35},
{Geo:"US West",SalesStage:"Qualified",count:16,pipelinevalue:6},
{Geo:"US East",SalesStage:"Qualified",count:3,pipelinevalue:3},
{Geo:"US East",SalesStage:"Identified",count:50,pipelinevalue:6},
{Geo:"US West",SalesStage:"Identified",count:39,pipelinevalue:3},
{Geo:"NSU",SalesStage:"Identified",count:20,pipelinevalue:8}];
data=summary_data.sort((a, b) => a.Geo.localeCompare(b.Geo));
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

expected as

```
[
{Geo:"NSU",SalesStage:"Identified",count:20,pipelinevalue:8},
{Geo:"US East",SalesStage:"Identified",count:50,pipelinevalue:6},
{Geo:"US East",SalesStage:"Qualified",count:3,pipelinevalue:3},
{Geo:"US East",SalesStage:"Closed Won",count:8,pipelinevalue:35},
{Geo:"US West",SalesStage:"Identified",count:39,pipelinevalue:3},
{Geo:"US West",SalesStage:"Qualified",count:16,pipelinevalue:6},
{Geo:"US West",SalesStage:"Closed Won",count:2,pipelinevalue:356}
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a sorting for `SalesStage`. This works with an object and order values for the stages.

```js
const
    summary_data = [{ Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Closed Won", count: 2, pipelinevalue: 356 }, { Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Closed Won", count: 8, pipelinevalue: 35 }, { Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 16, pipelinevalue: 6 }, { Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 3, pipelinevalue: 3 }, { Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 50, pipelinevalue: 6 }, { Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 39, pipelinevalue: 3 }, { Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 20, pipelinevalue: 8 }],
    order = { Identified: 1, Qualified: 2, 'Closed Won': 3 };

summary_data.sort((a, b) =>
    a.Geo.localeCompare(b.Geo) ||
    order[a.SalesStage] - order[b.SalesStage]
);

console.log(summary_data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: is it poissible to add one more sort (a, b) =>
    a.Geo.localeCompare(b.Geo)  for another field in or condition

Comment: @user3386779, yes it is, just chain with another [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) in the wanted priority.

Answer (score 1):

Try using[`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Within the callback, have it sort by `Geo`, but if they're the same in the objects being compared, then have it sort by `SalesStage`. Return the value of either the comparison of `Geo` or `SalesStage`, depending on which is relevant.